# How to develop apps for android TV (KitKat and below)?

Tags: android, android-tv

The minimum SDK version for developing apps for Android TV is limited to 5.0 (lollipop) in Android Studio. Then how to develop for lower platform versions?

Comment: [Android TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_TV) only runs Android 5.0 and higher.

Comment: Before Android TV, there was Google TV, and that was Android 3.x. If all you have is an old Google TV, you could probably download one of those older SDKs for Google TV. But be forewarned, many things are more difficult to do on a Google TV than on an Android TV, So you should consider buying one of those new cheap Android TVs (or buy a new cheap Lollipop Nexus tablet to simulate an Android TV).

Comment: Consider buying Nexus Player!

Answer (score 4):

Android TV works just on 5.0 and above. If you're developing an app for Google TV, then set the `minSDKversion` to something like 17 and build the app using those APIs.

The Leanback library seems to work on API level 17+, so you should be okay to use some of the same APIs on older devices.

Additionally, you can just not use Leanback and develop your own UI. The operating system is Android, so most of the APIs are the same. Plus if you support 17 and up, it'll run on Android TV